# My if/else is messing up

Tags: c++

```
cout << "Get ready to enter in the total rainfall for year " << yearCount << ".\n";
            for (months = 1; months <= 12; months ++)
                cout << "Please enter the total rainfall for ";
            if (months == 1)
                cout << "January.\n";
            else if (months == 2)
                cout << "February.\n";
            else if (months == 3)
                cout << "March.\n";
```

ect

I'm trying to make it to where each if statement will cout a name of a month instead of a number. however it just continues to loop "Please enter the total rainfall for " 12 times.

Comment: Of course it does. That's exactly what your code is written to do. Why would you expect it to do anything else?

Comment: Use brackets `{}`

Comment: Your for loop is only running the cout.  Use brackets !!

Comment: I would assume it to work because of the if statements checking for the months int, and then skipping over each other until the correct number coincides with the months int, then couts the name of the month and a new line.

Comment: To expand on the terminology a bit: `()` - parentheses, `[]` - brackets, `{}` - braces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are missing the block `{}` braces. Use:

```
for (months = 1; months <= 12; months ++)
{


}
```

Comment: It worked! I feel very dumb, but I'm glad my if statement idea worked. I just have to remember my brackets.
Sorry that you are getting downvoted for providing a proper answer.

Comment: I was waiting for the answer check to open up and then ended up going to eat. My bad.